# Cookies and multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

What are the rules regarding cookies and multiple browser tabs?

With two Firefox tabs open, I add a cookie set to expire in the future with Javascript in one Firefox tab. Then, in the second tab I print out the cookie via 'document.cookie' and the cookie I added in the other tab isn't there. I would expect cookies to synchronize between tabs. Is this not the case?

I'm also seeing that when I delete a cookie in one tab it isn't deleted in the other.

EDIT: This looks like a new bug in Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1450199

Comment: Cookies carry state info between client/server. Each tab is a separate and distinct client. They don't synchronize.

Comment: Chrome shares cookies between tabs based on my testing, so maybe it is browser dependent? I can add and remove cookies and both tabs stay synchronized with Chrome. 

Firefox seems to get an added cookie when the second tab refreshes.

Comment: Chrome is very, very inconsistent in this regard. For instance, I deleted a cookie from domain twitter.com (not the same host of page) and it did not delete in other tab. I created a cookie in one tab and it shows in other. I delete that very cookie in one tab it _did not_ delete in the other.  I would not rely on your findings.

Comment: There was a time when Chrome persisted `sessionStorage()` from closed tabs as long as any other tab remained open. Chrome is not the standard of perfection.

Comment: I encounter the same error and use _localStorage_ as the additional channel of communication among tabs.